# Error downloading VirtualBox installer from within Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file I wrote called vbox_install.bat that downloads VirtualBox for Windows from the correct web address. Below are the commands that I used to download the file:

```
set /p download=Please enter the location you wish to download the VirtualBox executable: 
echo Downloading VirtualBox 4.3.20 now...
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.20/VirtualBox-4.3.20-96997-Win.exe', '%download%\vboxinstall.exe') 
echo Download successful
goto INSTALL

:INSTALL
%download%\vboxinstall.exe
```

A couple of days ago when I ran this, the installer would open up after downloading and run correctly. When I run it today--on two different computers and after trying to download it to different drives--the VirtualBox installer gives the error "Invalid Drive: h:\". Note that I have been installing it to H:\Profile\Desktop, which is a network drive. But I also have tried downloading it to a USB drive F:\ and the exact same error comes up.

When I download the same installer by going through a web browser, the installer works just fine regardless of which drive I put the installer in. I checked to make sure the download link is the same as the one in my batch file.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I think I fixed it. I made the executable download with the words `VirtualBox` in it, and it runs just fine. Seems that there is some sort of check within the installer to make sure it looks like what Oracle wants it to be.

Comment: If you found a solution you should add it as an answer...